# How to extend grab-able area in Sortable jQuery UI Accordion with table header

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-accordion

I have this sortable accordion with a table in the header. The table is straight-forward: 2 rows and 3 columns, with the center column spanned over both rows, so in total 5 elements.

In the central element I use an input-element:

```
<div id="accordion" 
     data-bind="jqAccordion: { },template: { name: 'task-template', foreach: ¨Tasks, afterAdd: function(elem){$(elem).trigger('valueChanged');} }">
</div>   

<script type="text/html" id="task-template">
    <div data-bind="attr: {'id': 'Task' + TaskId}, click: $root.SelectedTask" class="group">
        <div class="accordion-header">
            <table class="myAccordionHeader" >
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="left-upper" >
                            <label for="SequenceNo">Seq:</label>
                            <span data-bind="text: SequenceNo"></span>
                        </td>
                        <td class="center" rowspan="2" >
                            <h3><b><input name="TaskName" data-bind="value: TaskName" /></b></h3>
                        </td>
                        <td class="right-upper" colspan="2">
                            Due: <span data-bind="text: DueDate"></span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="left-bottom">
                            Id: <span data-bind="text: TaskId" ></span>
                        </td>
                        <td class="right-bottom">
                            Status: <span data-bind="text: TaskStatus"></span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="myAccordionContent">
            <!-- Contents here... -->
        </div>    
    </div>
</script>
```

After introducing the table in the header, the only spots where I can grab my accordion header is in the input-elements margin, and to the side of it before the third column starts.

I reckon this has to do with some basic event on the tables data elements (`<td>`s).
The other `<td>`s are filled with text and `<span>` elements data-bound with knockout variables.

Any clue on how to expand the "grabable" area for the accordion?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you're binding `click` event to div that contains your accordion elements. So after you click on accordion header `click` event bubble to `div`

The easiest way i see is to add another dom element to bind on him `$root.SelectedTask`, like this:

```
<div data-bind="attr: {'id': 'Task' + TaskId}" class="group">
    <a href="javascript:;" data-bind="click: $root.SelectedTask">Any text</a>
... another html....
```

Try this, I hope that will help you.